# ¿calcular los años trascurridos a partir de una fecha en GoLang?

Tags: date, go

Hola a todos de ante mano, gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios, mi pregunta es sencilla, estoy aprendiendo GO y no sé cómo hacer esto, quiero obtener los años transcurridos a partir de una fecha dada en Golang es decir, tengo la siguiente fecha guardada en una variable:

```
date :=  "2020-08-16"
```

Quiero obtener los años que han transcurrido a la fecha actual (2022).

Comment: Una pregunta aparentemente sencilla, hasta que descubres que la api de fechas de goland no te lo permite hacer de forma simple con una alta precisión. Mi primer acercamiento fue decirte que usaras `date.Sub` o `time.Since`, pero resulta que el tipo `Duration` no puede convertirse directamente a años, hay que hacer algo [cómo esto](https://gosamples.dev/difference-between-dates/), lo cual no es exactamente preciso. Que curioso que no exista esta funcionalidad. Luego me encontré con [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530251/time-since-with-months-and-years) q te recomiendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que la fecha actual la obtienes con `currentTime := time.Now()` y que una [duración](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) sólo [se expresa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411576/236345) en horas, minutos y segundos, sería algo como

```
func main() {
    // Fecha actual con hora actual
    currentTime := time.Now()

    // Ubicación, zona horaria
    loc := currentTime.Location()

    //La fecha pasada que tienes
    pasttimestr := "2020-08-16 00:00"

    // El formato que le decimos que use para leer las fechas
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04"

    //Convertir tu fecha pasada a date
    pasttime, err := time.ParseInLocation(layout, pasttimestr, loc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Calculas la diferencia
    diff := pasttime.Sub(currentTime)

    // Informas el resultado en minutos
    fmt.Printf("La diferencia es %v, o %v en minutos\n", diff, diff.Minutes())
}
```

Y luego parsear eso a días, meses y años, dividiendo como toda la vida las horas por 24 para obtener días y de ahí, seguir.

Comment: El problema con ello es que tienes que dividir los minutos /60/24/30/365 para obtener los años como quiere el usuario y la precisión es bastante mala, ya que ni todos los meses tienen 30 días, ni todos los años tienen 365, sin contar los cambios de horario. Yo quedé bastante sorprendido que no se pudiera hacer de manera directa como en otros lenguajes.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Sí, así es pero _es lo menor peor que hay_. Por eso _se deja al lector_ la precisión

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, tienes mi voto. Para una aplicación que no requiera tanta precisión, la solución es totalmente válida. Solo te recomiendo que tu respuesta la des en años como dicta la pregunta, no en minutos.  También  corregir de mi comentario que la división sería  *`/60/24/365`. Se me fue un 30.